# Lapis: could not load `etlua` file

Tags: nginx, lua

I have got hello.etlua @ /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/views/
etlua already installed by luarocks. OS Debian.
This code

```
local lapis = require("lapis")

local app = lapis.Application()
app:enable("etlua")

app:match("/", function()
return { render: "hello" }
end)

return app
```

gives me such error:
Error

> /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/application.lua:121: module
>   'views.index' not found: no field package.preload['views.index']could
>   not load etlua file no file './lua/views/index.lua' no file
>   '/etc/nginx/lua/views/index.lua' no file './views/index.lua' no file
>   '/usr/local/share/luajit-2.1.0-alpha/views/index.lua' no file
>   '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/views/index.lua' no file
>   '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/views/index/init.lua' no file
>   './views/index.so' no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/views/index.so' no
>   file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so' no file './views.so' no file
>   '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/views.so' no file
>   '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so' Traceback
>
> stack traceback: [C]: in function 'require'
>   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/application.lua:121: in function
>   'render' /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/application.lua:406: in
>   function  [C]: in function 'xpcall'
>   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/application.lua:400: in function
>   'dispatch' /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/nginx.lua:181: in function
>   'serve' content_by_lua:2: in function

Usual template works properly:

```
local template = etlua.compile([[
Hello <%= name %>,
Here are your items:
<% for i, item in pairs(items) do %>

<%= item -%> <% end %> ]])
print(template({
name = "leafo",
items = { "Shoe", "Reflector", "Scarf" }
}))
```

I recieve the data in the log-file.
What is it? What I'm doing wrong? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package.path = '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/?.lua;' .. package.path
local lapis = require("lapis")
```

Comment: Thanks. Better but now I'm getting this error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/etlua.lua:3 loop or previous error loading module 'etlua'

Comment: I could be wrong but looks like your code is trying to load etlua from different locations, 1st "etlua already installed by luarocks", 2nd lapis loading /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/etlua.lua

Comment: There are three files "etlua.lua" in FS: /urs/local/share/lua/5.1/etlua.lua , /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/etlua.lua , /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/features/etlua.lua  But if I rename the first file, nothing happens - the same error:(

Comment: Pathes to search (after updating) /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/?.lua;
./lua/?.lua;
/etc/nginx/lua/?.lua;
./?.lua;
/usr/local/share/luajit-2.1.0-alpha/?.lua;
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;

Comment: Oh gosh, I found the problem. It was near  your idea. Just wrong path to read views. not lapis but the parent of it

Comment: So, is this your answer? Mark it please :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is wrong path of view. I put files at `/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/views`. But this is incorrect. The correct location is `/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/views`.